# Removing the star without changing homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

I know that if the link of a simplex $\sigma$ in a finite simplicial complex $K$ is contractible then the two complexes $K$ and $K\setminus \text{Star}(\sigma)$
share the same homotopy type.

Basically, if the link of $\sigma$ is contractible then it can be reduced to a point by a sequence of collapses and anti-collapses and, from this sequence, one can deduces a sequence of collapses and anti-collapses that reduces $K$ to $K\setminus \text{Star}(\sigma)$.

I am wondering if there is some similar result with homology.
Namely,  if the link of $\sigma$ in $K$ is acyclic, is it true that 
$K$ and $K\setminus \text{Star}(\sigma)$ have the same homology groups?

I would really appreciate any idea, reference or counter-example!

Comment: Yes this is true. Use Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: Thanks! I am really not an expert in homology but your pointer is going to help a lot.

Comment: Oops I added a wrong answer which I've deleted!