# Necessary condition for removing a simplex and changing homotopy type.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In a finite simplicial complex $K$, if the link of a simplex $\sigma$ is contractible then the two complexes $K$ and $K\setminus \text{Star}(\sigma)$ share the same homotopy type.

I am wondering if the converse is also true. Namely, if the link $\sigma$ of a simplicial complex $K$ is *not* contractible, is it true that $K$ and $K\setminus \text{Star}(\sigma)$ have *different* homotopy types?

I once post a similar question about how removing the star of a simplex in a simplicial complex alters its topology : [Removing the star without changing homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398448/removing-the-star-without-changing-homology) but I am stuck for this question as well as it requires different tools. Indeed, I do not know how to show that the homotopy type of two spaces differs beside exhibiting an invariant that is not maintained (I did not have any in this case from my current topological toolbox).

I would really appreciate any comment, idea or reference on this question.

Comment: A note: the Euler characteristic of the link needs to be $1$ in order for the complexes to have the same homotopy type. However that's quite far from saying it's contractible.